# My query gives result set but I can't create procedure with that query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I created a query using Cursor.It Gives the result set.But If I tried to Create it as a 'Procedure'.It throws error 'Invalid Column Name'.

My Piece Of query which produces result:

```
DECLARE @ContactID INT, @ActivityID INT, @RecurrencePattern INT, @Day   VARCHAR(50), @DayPattern VARCHAR(50), @Month INT, @StartDate DATETIME, @EndDate DATETIME, @Frequency VARCHAR(50),

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR  
SELECT RT.ContactID, RT.ActivityID, F.Frequency, RT.RecurrencePattern, RT.Day, RT.DayPattern, RT.Month, RT.StartDate, ISNULL(RT.EndDate, 
    DATEADD(MONTH,((YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH, 3, GETDATE())) - 1900) * 12) + MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, 3, GETDATE())),-1)) AS EndDate
FROM tblrecurringtasks RT
    INNER JOIN luFrequency F ON F.FrequencyID = RT.FrequencyID
WHERE RT.TaskID = xx ;

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF 

OPEN db_cursor   
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @ContactID, @ActivityID, @Frequency, @RecurrencePattern, @Day, @DayPattern, @Month, @StartDate, @EndDate
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN 
SET @Running_date = @StartDate;
SET @temp_Date = @StartDate;
DECLARE @RPattern INT = 0;
WHILE @Running_date <= @EndDate
BEGIN
    DECLARE @WeekDay INT = DATEPART(dw, @Running_date)

    IF @Frequency = "Daily"
    BEGIN   
        BEGIN
            BEGIN
                PRINT 'X'
                  BREAK
                END
                SET @DayList = STUFF(@DayList, 1, CHARINDEX(',', @DayList+','), '')
            END
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            BEGIN
               PRINT 'y'
                SET @temp_Date = @temp_Date + @RecurrencePattern
            END
        END
    END
```

My select Query produces the result for frequency as 'Daily'.so the query works for me. But If I try to create procedure like this,

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_InsertRecurringTasks]
@TaskID int
AS 
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
*/  Above query */
END
```

It throws the Error Invalid column name 'Daily'.
What might be the Issue.how to solve it.Help me on this.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Perhaps you need `BEGIN` and `END`.

Comment: Why is Daily contained in double quotations? Should it not be single quotations? 'Daily'...

Comment: One `END` is missing in the last. Also escaping the reserved keywords `Day` and `Month` with `[ ]`, like `[Day]` and `[Month]`

Comment: @Leonidas199x  yeah that's the issue bro..it works with single quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not check for a string using double quotes, the following code will give the same error:

```
DECLARE @Frequency NVARCHAR(4);

SELECT @Frequency = 'Test';

IF @Frequency = "Test"
PRINT 'Yes';
```

Where as, this will work:

```
DECLARE @Frequency NVARCHAR(4);

SELECT @Frequency = 'Test';

IF @Frequency = 'Test'
PRINT 'Yes';
```

Comment: Ain't no problem, brosef.